# How can I get values of key with 'hget' command in redis with lua script

Tags: lua, redis

I'd like to summary key values of monthly with 'hget' command.

Test Set)
    hmset SiteID:TotalCnt 20180101 10 20180102 2 20180103 5 20180120 10 20180131 30 20180205 20 20180210 5

I'd like to summary key values of 2018.01
So, I did..

sumkey.lua

```
local mon = ARGV[1]
local sumkey = 0
local forkey = ''
for i = 1,31 do
    if i < 10 then local dd = '0' .. tostring(i)
    else dd = tostring(i)
    end 
    forkey = mon .. dd
    sumkey = sumkey + redis.call('hget' , KEYS[1] , forkey)
 end
 return sumkey
```

ubuntu@:~$ redis-cli -n 2 --eval sumkey.lua
(error) ERR Error running script (call to f_1c9d9d311f9c1e2fbb34fa81176539ad45da3b5b): @enable_strict_lua:15: user_script:8: Script attempted to access unexisting global variable 'dd'

tostring does not work.!!!

How can I summary values of key ???

Answer (score 3):

Try to declare it(`dd`) before the loop.
The problem is that if the `if` statement is not satisfied, the `dd` variable is not defined, so it tries to find a global variable with this name.

Comment: Adding `local` after `else` is not going to work, as it will keep the value localize to only that `else` block.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko That's right, my bad! I've edited the answer, so it can be approved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to "localize" the variable before the `if ... then` branch as otherwise it only stays "visible" inside that branch and after leaving the branch the value is restored to whatever it was before that:

```
local dd
if i < 10 then dd = '0' .. tostring(i)
else dd = tostring(i)
end
```

You can also convert it to one expression:

```
local dd = i < 10 and '0' .. tostring(i) or tostring(i)
```

or use `format`:

```
forkey = mon .. ("%02d"):format(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it.

See below.

:sumkey.lua

```
local key, mon = KEYS[1], ARGV[1]
local subkey
local sumkey, keyval= 0

for i = 1,31 do
    if i < 10 then subkey = mon .. '0' .. tostring(i)
    else subkey = mon .. tostring(i)
    end

    keyval = tonumber(redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],subkey))

    if keyval ~= nil then
        sumkey = sumkey + keyval
    end
end

return sumkey
```

ubuntu@$ redis-cli -n 2 --eval sumkey.lua  SiteID:TotalCnt , '201801'
(integer) 57

have a great day everyone ~~!!